# MS SQL Char() function when used in string sees combination of letters as special character

Tags: sql, sql-server

When running below code to check for special characters, it sees AE as a special character, whereas it is just a normal alphabet

```
declare @DSC2 varchar(10)='WITHAE' 

select CAST(CHARINDEX(CHAR(230), @DSC2) AS VARCHAR)
    + CHAR(47) + CAST(LEN(@DSC2) AS VARCHAR)
    + CHAR(44) + CHAR(32)
```

Result
5/6,

Looking at some data on internet, \AE in LATEX is a special character æ
Hence, the above query is showing me that on 5th place of the string, there is a special character. Whereas, in reality it is not.

Similarly, If I run below query, it shows 3/6 because in LATEX \TH is a special character Þ

```
declare @DSC2 varchar(10)='WITHAE'

select CAST(CHARINDEX(CHAR(254), @DSC2) AS VARCHAR)
    + CHAR(47) + CAST(LEN(@DSC2) AS VARCHAR)
    + CHAR(44) + CHAR(32)
```

Similarly, if I run below query, it shows 5/6 because in LATEX \oe is a special character œ

```
declare @DSC2 varchar(10)='mydjoe'

select CAST(CHARINDEX(CHAR(140), @DSC2) AS VARCHAR)
    + CHAR(47) + CAST(LEN(@DSC2) AS VARCHAR)
    + CHAR(44) + CHAR(32)
```

Expecting 0/6, but result came as 5/6 because it saw oe as an abbreviation of special character œ.

How do I fix this? This should not be a special character and it should show me 0/6 because no special character is there.

[Snapshot of LATEX Symbol List (https://math.uoregon.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/compsymb-1qyb3zd.pdf)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMdiS.png)

Comment: What is your default collation for your database? Run `SELECT CONVERT (varchar(256), SERVERPROPERTY('collation'))` or `SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME()`.

Comment: If you don't want `AE`and `æ` to compare as equal then you  need to use a collation with the semantics you want

Comment: Probably that will turn out to be a binary collation as it looks like in most collations except some Scandinavian ones `ae` and `æ` do compare as equal (exceptions are things like Danish_Greenlandic, Danish_Norwegian, Icelandic, Norwegian, Sami_Norway, Sami_Sweden_Finland)

Comment: Replacing `@DSC2` with `@DSC2 COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin` in the expression will override any existing collation and dumb down the string so that there are no special semantics.

Comment: It's not just SQL Server BTW. I'm using Google Chrome and if I find `œ` or `æ` on the page it highlights the instances of `oe` and `ae` (respectively) too

Comment: Fyi, you should always specify the lengths of your `varchar`s else if will get truncated to the default length which will cause annoying results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select a collation that gives you your desired comparison semantics for [Þ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)), [œ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92), and [æ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86).

You can find all of these ones with

```
DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @DynSQL = STRING_AGG(CAST('select ''' + name + ''' where N''oe'' <> N''Œ'' COLLATE ' + name + ' AND N''ae'' <> N''æ'' COLLATE ' + name + '  AND N''th'' <> N''Þ'' COLLATE ' + name AS varchar(MAX)), ' UNION ALL ')
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()

EXEC (@DynSQL)
```

The choices are basically use a binary one or a Scandinavian one ([full results](https://dbfiddle.uk/B4skJ8vU)).

Once you've selected one you can use the `COLLATE` clause if you just want to apply it to specific situations.

Comment: Thanks Martin and TN. Both of your suggestions helped clarify and resolve the issues.